# Get value from data base using AsyncTask and change TextView value in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

As explained in the title, I want get a value from  a database using `AsyncTask` and change `TextView` text in a Fragment.

I don't have any problem to use `AsyncTask` and get the value from the database. But when I change the `TextView` text (from within a fragment) I receive this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kirolm.instalacionesdep, PID: 14072
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.HomeFragment.writeTextViewsTituloDelPeriodico(HomeFragment.java:206)
at com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.asynctask.LoadLastNewAsync.onPostExecute(LoadLastNewAsync.java:92)
at com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.asynctask.LoadLastNewAsync.onPostExecute(LoadLastNewAsync.java:1)
06-at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I Launch `AsyncTask` in `HomeFragment.java` (onCreate method):

```
context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
LoadLastNewAsync llna = new LoadLastNewAsync(context, lang);
llna.execute();
```

I declare `TextView` in `onCreateView` method:

```
tv_tituloNoticia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment_tv_titulo_noticia);
```

This is the `onPostExecute` method (`LoadLastNewAsync.java`):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    homeFragment.writeTextViewsTituloDelPeriodico(tituloAviso);
}
```

`WriteTextViewTituloDelPeriodico` is a public method in `HomeFragment`.

```
public void writeTextViewsTituloDelPeriodico(String texto){
       tv_tituloNoticia.setText(texto);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: define `tv_tituloNoticia`  globally OR pass `tv_tituloNoticia` as Argument to `AsyncTask`

Comment: You're creating an instance of HomeFragment, but you're not attaching it to the Activity.

Comment: Check "tituloAviso" string is null

Comment: According to Fragment life-cycle onCreate() is called before onCreateView() ,when you are starting AsyncTask in onCreate it is running in separate thread and there might be possibility that onPostExecute of Async task get called before onCreateView ,that is the main reason you are getting NullPointerException as view are not initialized

Comment: @Rahul you are wrong about onCreate ... if you did not use fragment manager then even onCreate wasn't called ... also onPostExecute is called on the UI thread ... but generaly you are right about one thing *view are not initialized* **solution:** pass the text as arguments and use em in onCreateView

Comment: I defined `tv_tituloNoticias` in HomeFragment as `public TextView tv_tituloNoticia;`

Comment: **define** not **set**

Comment: If i write LoadLastNewAsync in the same file (inside HomeFragment class) that work ok. But i want write in another file.

Comment: @Selvin Yes onPostExecute is running on UI thread , but doInBackground of Async Task is called in separated thread and after thread finished its work control is given to onPostExecute . So we have to make sure view are initialized first then Asnc call should in order reflect changes on UI element

Comment: ughh, ok where on hell between this 2 lines are onCreateView called?: `homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    homeFragment.writeTextViewsTituloDelPeriodico(tituloAviso);` @Rahul if you do not add the Fragment to the FragmentManager the fragment's lifecycle do not even start ...

Comment: @Selvin You proposed me that my asynctask must return text to HomeFragment. Is this correct?

Comment: @Selvin it clearly mention in question 
I Launch AsynctTask in HomeFragment.java (onCreate method):
and 
I declare TextView in onCreatView method:

Comment: Then it is used on wrong instance of HomeFragment... Not the one that had started the AsyncTask but the new one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

I modified my `AsyncTask` and now it returns a `String`.
In the HomeFragment (`onCreate` method) I execute my `AsyncTask` and receive a `String`:

```
            LoadLastNewAsync llna = new LoadLastNewAsync(context, lang);

            try {
                tituloAviso = llna.execute().get();
                Log.d("Testing", "El valor del string recibido es: "+tituloAviso);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In the `onCreateView` method I set TextView using tituloAviso.

This is LoadLastAsync.java code.

```
public class LoadLastNewAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
    Context context;
    private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    private String tituloAviso;
    private Aviso aviso;
    private String lang;
    private HomeFragment homeFragment;


    //constructor
    public LoadLastNewAsync(Context context, String lang) {
         this.context = context;
         this.lang = lang;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("Testing", "LoadLastNewAsync. Entra en doInBackGround");
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        boolean dbExist = myDbHelper.checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
            aviso = new Aviso();
            aviso = recuperarUltimoAviso();
            tituloAviso = aviso.getTitle();
        }

        return tituloAviso; 

    }

    private Aviso recuperarUltimoAviso() {
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            aviso = myDbHelper.getUltimoAviso(this.lang);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        myDbHelper.close();
        return aviso;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```